# Broken eth0 (not about strange name)

Tags: internet, ethernet-port

Well, when I got my RPi3B+ all was gud as it should be(probably). But now my Ethernet port just don't work. Many distros just don't shows eth0 (or neb24dfaw or how it...) (like with ifconfig -a) and "dmesg" shows this

`[   10.168818] brcmfmac: F1 signature read @0x18000000=0x15264345
[   10.181799] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_map_chip_to_name: using brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio.bin for chip 0x004345(17221) rev 0x000006
[   10.182176] usbcore: registered new interface driver brcmfmac
[   10.428317] random: crng init done
[   10.471433] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware version = wl0: Feb 27 2018 03:15:32 version 7.45.154 (r684107 CY) FWID 01-4fbe0b04
[   10.472228] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: CLM version = API: 12.2 Data: 9.10.105 Compiler: 1.29.4 ClmImport: 1.36.3 Creation: 2018-03-09 18:56:28`

And the most serious

`[   29.135899] lan78xx 1-1.1.1:1.0 eth0: no PHY found`

But i found one distro that shows up eth0 at ifconfig -a
But when i try to "sudo ifconfig eth0 up" or any orher way that what i get

```
SIOCSIFFLAGS: Input/output error
```

WELL, Idk what to do. (I AM SURE THAT ETH CABLE IS CONNECTED HOW IT SHOULD WORK)

(/etc/network/interfaces at distro w/ "working" eth0)

`# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
 # Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
 # For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'
 # Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d`

Ah! Almost forgot. Lights at port don't work but at one distro (kali) at first boot it showed up.

Comment: "no PHY found" is not about a disconnected network cable. If you get this on a vanilla Raspbian, it's likely that your Ethernet chip died. You can still get an external USB-to-Ethernet dongle to get the network working.

Comment: Well, it's really sad.